# create hierarchy of roles on a jhipster monolithic application

Tags: jhipster

i'd like to add 4 more user roles in my monolithic jhipster application ( client , seller , membreJure , and agentService) so that every client and seller will have a personal profile ,but under the control of the agentService( an agentService will control the clients and sellers of a city)
could jhipster help in with some trics to simplify my work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's up to you to code it with the help of spring-security.